# How to change product price in sub website

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have `Magento ver. 1.9.2.1`, I have setup two sub website with two sub domain.
I have more than 30,000 products in magento site which are global to all website.

Main Website has base currency INR and other two sub website has base currency USD, AED.
Frontend on product page for main website price showing correct but for other two website product price showing incorrect.

```
For Example : 

Product price in INR is 5000 Rs

then in USD sub website it is showing 5000 USD => 3,37,552 INR

and similarly for AED sub website
```

I want to auto set all product price in converted form in their respective base currency, because it is too much time consuming if I do from admin.

```
It should be :

Product price in INR is 5000 Rs

then in USD sub website it is showing 74.030 USD => 5000 INR
```

Is there any setting or any php script for solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow bellow steps**

**Step : 1** (First domain): Go admin side `System -> Configuration`

Set **"Indian Rupee"** in `Base Currency`, `Base Currency` & `Allowed Currencies` & save this setting to click top right site button "**Save Config**".

[image]
**Step : 2** (Second domain) Go admin side `System -> Configuration`

First select second website in top left site `Current Configuration Scope`.

After select "Us Dollor" in fields `Default Display Currency` & `Allowed Currencies` and save this setting  to click top right button "**Save Config"**.

[image]

**Step : 3** Go admin side `System -> Manage Currency -> Rates`

First click `Import` button to get current currency rates and after save currency rates to via `Save Currency Rates`.

[image]

Comment: Please read my question first. I have setup already all above steps and it is working on frontend but the problem is with product price which is not showing correct.

Comment: But what is issue? Currency rates issue?